# Swift implementation of minimal binary search tree is going over Infinite recursion

Tags: swift, algorithm, recursion

For last one day, I am trying to figure out why this function is going for infinite recursion.

I have implemented in Python with the same logic and it works flawlessly. I even tried left only and right only recursion call and the loop stops but when done together this goes for infinite calls.

```
public class BSTNode<T: Comparable> {
    var data: T

    var left: BSTNode<T>?
    var right: BSTNode<T>?

    init(data: T) {
        self.data = data
    }

}



func minimalTree(startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int, array: [Int]) -> BSTNode<Int>? {

    if startIndex >= endIndex {
        return nil
    }

    print("start \(startIndex)")
    print("end \(endIndex)")


    let midIndex = Int((startIndex + endIndex / 2))
    let midElement = array[midIndex]
    let root = BSTNode(data: midElement)

    root.left = minimalTree(startIndex: startIndex, endIndex: midIndex - 1, array: array)
    root.right = minimalTree(startIndex: midIndex + 1, endIndex: endIndex, array: array)

    return root
}

func minimalTreeTest() {

    let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]


    _ = minimalTree(startIndex: 0, endIndex: array.count - 1, array: array)
}
```

Comment: The parentheses in the calculation of `midIndex` are wrong.

Comment: `(startIndex + endIndex / 2)` ↦ `(startIndex + endIndex) / 2`

Comment: @kennytm thanks a lot. Sometimes your eyes doesn't get catch one these :)